# PostgreSQL name conventions for Field names of a table

Tags: database, postgresql, field, naming-conventions

I want to know if there some document, standard or RFC for naming conventions in DATABASE, TABLE and FIELD NAMES for PostgreSQL. I have found this question:

[PostgreSQL naming conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878248/postgresql-naming-conventions)

But there's no have a source and didn't explain the naming conventions.

Comment: You're asking about a "convention" rather than a policy... why do you expect that there will be some official documentation? Based on my experience reading and writing SQL in PostgreSQL-based applications, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2878408/20789) by @leonbloy is a good description of most PG users' practice.

Comment: In addition to this having a duplicate, it's also really off topic for stack overflow and would generally be closed as "primarily opinion based" per the Help pages.