# update query not working on Heroku using cloud 9 command line

Tags: sql, postgresql, heroku, rails-postgresql

I have the following tables:

[image]

and the users table contains the following columns:

[image]

I am trying to run the following statement:

> UPDATE users SET isTeacher = 'TRUE' WHERE id = '2';

but I am getting the following error message:

```
ERROR:  column "isteacher" of relation "users" does not exist
LINE 1: UPDATE users SET isTeacher = 'TRUE' WHERE id = '2';
                         ^
```

Please not that there is a user with id of 2. So What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had once the same problem. I think the problem is that u have it as **isTeacher**. u need to convert it to **isteacher** or **is_teacher**. I hope that helped. check this link: [PostgreSQL naming conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878248/postgresql-naming-conventions)