# How to create a JOIN in Postgres with a foreign key created by TypeORM

Tags: typescript, postgresql, orm, typeorm

Some quick context, I come from MySQL and I created a custom ORM similar to .NET's Dapper package. I've been using my custom ORM with MySQL for a long time now but it's not documented so it's hard to hire developers and expect them to be efficient.

I decided that I would try to migrate to Postgres (so I can use Hasura in the future), I'm using TypeORM right now. I created the tables using TypeORM entities. Now, I can't do a simple query with a JOIN which works just fine in MySQL.

Here is an example:

**user table**

- id (pk)
- first_name
- last_name

**address table**

- id (pk)
- address
- city
- state
- zip
- userId (fk)

**Query**

```sql
SELECT
    user.id,
    user.first_name,
    user.last_name,
    address.address,
    address.city
FROM
    debtor
INNER JOIN address 
    ON user.id = address.userId;
```

**Error**

```sh
ERROR:  column address.userid does not exist
LINE 12:     ON user.id = address.userId;
                            ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "address.userId".
SQL state: 42703
Character: 300
```

I've tried a bunch of different JOIN types, I've tried aliases, I've tried alternate formatting.

**Notes**

- TypeORM created the `address.userId` foreign key column which matches `user.id`
- The error is transposing the column name to all lowercase `column address.userid does not exist`

**This is the TypeORM entity**

```js
// User.ts

...

  @OneToMany(() => Address, (address: Address) => address.user, {
    nullable: true,
    cascade: true,
    eager: true,
  })
  addresses: Address[];
```

```js
// Address.ts

...
@ManyToOne(() => User, (user: User) => user.addresses)
  @JoinColumn()
  user: User;
```

Comment: Can you post the TypeORM query?

Comment: In addition, I suggest you to follow the PostgreSQL naming convention (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878248/postgresql-naming-conventions/2878408)) since in the future it's more easier and clearer to understand for others.
Change ```@JoinColumn()``` to ```@JoinColumn({ name: 'user_id' })```. Remove ```nullable: true, cascade: true``` from ```@OneToMany(...)``` and move them into ```@ManyToOne(...)``` decorator. PS: I think that ```nullable``` should be ```false``` since an address *must* be related to a *user*.

Comment: This is it ^^ @CarloCorradini - thank you!