# How to solve the error "errorMissingColumn" on a snakecase id column in entity framework 5?

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, .net-core, json-api

I am building an API which is accessing a PostgreSQL database using DotNet 5.0, JsonAPIDotNetCore and EntityFramework. I have generated my Models and my DbContext with dotnet-ef as I am doing *database-first* (there will be changes on the database in the near future). When I launch the API and I am trying to access a resource, the API respond an error 500 with this error in the debug console:

```
Exception data:
    Severity: ERROR
    SqlState: 42703
    MessageText: column j.id doesn't exist
    Position: 56
    File: d:\pginstaller_13.auto\postgres.windows-x64\src\backend\parser\parse_relation.c
    Line: 3514
    Routine: errorMissingColumn
```

### Database

The Table `Jobs` I'm trying to access:

| Column | Type | Collationnement | NULL-able | Default |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **id_job** | bigint |  | not null | generated always as identity |
| inserted_date | timestamp with time zone |  | not null |  |
| path | ltree |  | not null |  |
| name | character varying(260) |  | not null |  |

Index :

```
"Jobs_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id_job)
```

Referenced by :

```
TABLE ""Versions"" CONSTRAINT "Versions_id_job_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (id_job) REFERENCES "Jobs"(id_job) NOT VALID
```

Notice, I am using snake_case as proven to be a [postgresql naming convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878248/postgresql-naming-conventions)

### Model

Then I use [the command documented by the Npgsql EF Core provider](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/#using-an-existing-database-database-first) which generate my `DbContext`. Here is the model with annotations:

```cs
[DisplayName("job")]
[Table("Jobs")]
public partial class Job : Identifiable
{
    public Job()
    {
        Versions = new HashSet<Version>();
    }

    [Attr(PublicName = "id-job")]
    public long IdJob { get; set; }

    [Attr(PublicName = "inserted-date")]
    public DateTime InsertedDate { get; set; }

    [Attr(PublicName = "path")]
    public string Path { get; set; }

    [Attr(PublicName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Attr(PublicName = "versions")]
    [ForeignKey("id_version")]
    public virtual ICollection<Version> Versions { get; set; }
}
```

### DbContext

And here an extract of the model builder (using Fluent API):

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasPostgresExtension("adminpack")
                    .HasPostgresExtension("ltree")
                    .HasAnnotation("Relational:Collation", "French_France.1252");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Job>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => e.IdJob)
                      .HasName("Jobs_pkey");

                entity.Property(e => e.IdJob)
                      .HasColumnName("id_job")
                      .UseIdentityAlwaysColumn();

                entity.Property(e => e.InsertedDate)
                      .HasColumnType("timestamp with time zone")
                      .HasColumnName("inserted_date");

                entity.Property(e => e.Name)
                      .IsRequired()
                      .HasMaxLength(260)
                      .HasColumnName("name");

                entity.Property(e => e.Path)
                      .IsRequired()
                      .HasColumnType("ltree")
                      .HasColumnName("path");
            });
        
        [...]
        
        OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
    }
```

### Services Configuration

Finally, in the services configuration, I have added the DbContext with the connection string and the naming convention [as proposed by the Npgsql EF Core provider documentation](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/modeling/table-column-naming.html):

```cs
services.AddDbContext<MyDatabaseDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnectionString"))
                                   .UseSnakeCaseNamingConvention());
```

### CsProj

Here is the csproj file :

```cs
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="EFCore.NamingConventions" Version="5.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="EntityFramework" Version="6.4.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="JsonApiDotNetCore" Version="4.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="5.0.8">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="5.0.8">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="5.0.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.6.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

After some experimentations, it seems that Entity Framework parse a snake_case column name `"id_something"` or `"something_id"` as `"id"`. Is this a normal behavior for Entity Framework ? How can I change it without compromising on the database naming convention ?

Comment: Based on the information provided there appears to be something in your model with a column name of 'id' that it is trying to resolve, and I would suspect it is in your `Identifiable` definition.

Comment: You're right, let me update this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**As supposed by [Steve Py](https://stackoverflow.com/users/423497/steve-py) *(Thank you very much)*, the problem come from JsonApiDotNetCore on the [id serializing](https://github.com/json-api-dotnet/JsonApiDotNetCore/issues/363).**

### Models

In my `Job` Model I need to change the name of the ressource Id (here, `JobId`), for `Id` which is a property of `Identifiable` to override. You need to specify the Type of the Id property to the generic interface [`Identifiable<TId>`](https://www.jsonapi.net/api/JsonApiDotNetCore.Resources.Identifiable-1.html). So I change those parts of the model:

```cs
public partial class Job : Identifiable
{

    [...]

    [Attr(PublicName = "id-job")]
    public long IdJob { get; set; }

    [...]

}
```

for this:

```cs
public partial class Job : Identifiable<long>
{

    [...]

    [Attr(PublicName = "id-job")]
    public override long Id { get; set; }

    [...]

}
```

I had to rename all occurrences of IdJob in the DbContext.

### Controller

Finally, I set my controller, specifying the type of the resource identifier for [`JsonApiController<TResource, TId>`](https://www.jsonapi.net/api/JsonApiDotNetCore.Controllers.JsonApiController-2.html) and [`IResourceService<TResource, TId>`](https://www.jsonapi.net/api/JsonApiDotNetCore.Services.IResourceService-2.html) as follow:

```cs
namespace TalendExplorerAPI.Controllers
{
    public class JobController : JsonApiController<Job, long>
    {

        public JobController(IJsonApiOptions options, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
            IResourceService<Job, long> resourceService)
            : base(options, loggerFactory, resourceService)
        {
        }
    

    }
}
```

If you are using VSCode, you might have two compiler errors on your controller. If this is the case, just reboot the IDE.