# improving query

Tags: subquery

IS there anyway i can improve this query?

```
SELECT DISTINCT adb_product_type.strproduct_type AS strproduct_type, adb_product_cat.strproduct_cat AS strproduct_cat, adb_product.strproduct AS strproduct, 

CASE @campaignCount:= 
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT adb_campaign_1.campaign_id) 
FROM adb_camp_media AS adb_camp_media_1 
LEFT JOIN adb_campaign AS adb_campaign_1 ON adb_campaign_1.campaign_id = adb_camp_media_1.campaign_id
LEFT JOIN adb_camp_media_prod AS adb_camp_media_prod_1 ON adb_camp_media_prod_1.media_num = adb_camp_media_1.media_num 
WHERE 
(adb_camp_media_1.inttotal_per_store = 1 AND adb_camp_media_1.lngproduct = adb_product.lngproduct OR adb_camp_media_1.inttotal_per_store > 1 AND adb_camp_media_prod_1.lngproduct = adb_product.lngproduct)
AND (
(
adb_campaign_1.start_date
BETWEEN '2011-01-01'
AND '2011-01-31'
)
OR (
adb_campaign_1.end_date
BETWEEN '2011-01-01'
AND '2011-01-31'
)
OR (
adb_campaign_1.start_date < '2011-01-01'
AND adb_campaign_1.end_date > '2011-01-31'
)
) 
) 
WHEN 0 THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END AS 'YesNo', 

CASE @campaignCount WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE @campaignCount END AS 'CampaignCount', 
CASE @campaignCount WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE 

(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT adb_media_1.name ORDER BY adb_media_1.name SEPARATOR ', ' ) 
FROM adb_camp_media AS adb_camp_media_1 
LEFT JOIN adb_campaign AS adb_campaign_1 ON adb_campaign_1.campaign_id = adb_camp_media_1.campaign_id 
LEFT JOIN adb_camp_media_prod AS adb_camp_media_prod_1 ON adb_camp_media_prod_1.media_num = adb_camp_media_1.media_num 
LEFT JOIN adb_media AS adb_media_1 ON adb_media_1.media_id = adb_camp_media_1.media_id
WHERE 
(adb_camp_media_1.inttotal_per_store = 1 AND adb_camp_media_1.lngproduct = adb_product.lngproduct OR adb_camp_media_1.inttotal_per_store > 1 AND adb_camp_media_prod_1.lngproduct = adb_product.lngproduct)
AND (
(
adb_campaign_1.start_date
BETWEEN '2011-01-01'
AND '2011-01-31'
)
OR (
adb_campaign_1.end_date
BETWEEN '2011-01-01'
AND '2011-01-31'
)
OR (
adb_campaign_1.start_date < '2011-01-01'
AND adb_campaign_1.end_date > '2011-01-31'
)
) 
) 

END AS mediaName , adb_product.lngproduct

FROM adb_product_type 
LEFT JOIN adb_product_cat ON adb_product_cat.lngproduct_type = adb_product_type.lngproduct_type 
LEFT JOIN adb_product ON adb_product.lngproduct_cat = adb_product_cat.lngproduct_cat 
LEFT JOIN adb_camp_media ON adb_camp_media.lngproduct = adb_product.lngproduct 
LEFT JOIN adb_media ON adb_media.media_id = adb_camp_media.media_id 
LEFT JOIN adb_camp_media_prod ON adb_camp_media_prod.media_num = adb_camp_media.media_num 
LEFT JOIN adb_campaign ON adb_campaign.campaign_id = adb_camp_media.campaign_id 
WHERE 1=1 


ORDER BY YesNo DESC , strproduct_type, strproduct_cat, strproduct
```

### TABLE STRUCTURE

### -- Table structure for table `adb_camp_media`

CREATE TABLE adb_camp_media (
  media_num int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  campaign_id int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  media_id int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  inttotal_per_store int(4) NOT NULL default '0',
  units_per_item int(2) default NULL,
  lngproduct int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  rental_cost double(10,2) default NULL,
  checkers_rental double default NULL,
  hyper_rental double default NULL,
  usave_rental double default NULL,
  ls_rental double(10,2) default '0.00',
  spar_rental double(10,2) default '0.00',
  backboard tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (media_num),
  KEY campaign_id (campaign_id,media_id,lngproduct),
  KEY lngproduct (lngproduct)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

---

--

### -- Table structure for table `adb_camp_media_prod`

CREATE TABLE adb_camp_media_prod (
  media_prod_id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  media_num int(4) NOT NULL,
  lngproduct int(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (media_prod_id),
  KEY media_num (media_num,lngproduct),
  KEY lngproduct (lngproduct)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

---

--

### -- Table structure for table `adb_campaign`

CREATE TABLE adb_campaign (
  campaign_id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  client_id int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  campaign_name varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
  description text,
  position_desc text,
  start_date date NOT NULL default '0000-00-00',
  end_date date NOT NULL default '0000-00-00',
  approved tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  created_date date NOT NULL default '0000-00-00',
  updated_date datetime default NULL,
  user_id int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  pinno varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
  jobno varchar(30) NOT NULL default '',
  quoteno varchar(30) NOT NULL default '',
  sales_ae_id int(11) default NULL,
  artwork_specno varchar(30) NOT NULL default '',
  artwork_jobno varchar(30) NOT NULL default '',
  agency tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  brand_name varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
  paypercycle tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  agency_comm double default NULL,
  variant varchar(100) default NULL,
  pack_size varchar(100) default NULL,
  discount double default NULL,
  discount_val double default NULL,
  sales_comm double NOT NULL default '0',
  cancelled tinyint(1) default '0',
  onhold tinyint(1) default '0',
  campaign_status_id int(4) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (campaign_id),
  UNIQUE KEY jobno (jobno),
  KEY start_date (start_date),
  KEY end_date (end_date),
  KEY campaign_name (campaign_name),
  KEY user_id (user_id,cancelled,onhold)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

---

--

### -- Table structure for table `adb_product`

CREATE TABLE adb_product (
  lngproduct int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  strproduct varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  lngproduct_cat int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (lngproduct),
  KEY lngproduct_cat (lngproduct_cat)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

---

--

### -- Table structure for table `adb_product_cat`

CREATE TABLE adb_product_cat (
  lngproduct_cat int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  strproduct_cat varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  lngproduct_type int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (lngproduct_cat),
  KEY lngproduct_type (lngproduct_type)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

---

--

### -- Table structure for table `adb_product_type`

CREATE TABLE adb_product_type (
  lngproduct_type int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  strproduct_type varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (lngproduct_type)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Comment: What does this query do? Show table structure and tell us what you want as output?

Comment: this query outputs a report of product types,product category,product -> the amount of campaigns assigned to that product and the amount of media assigned to each campaign

Comment: Please clean up the formatting. This code is next to unreadable. There is a thread on the subject here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/522356/what-sql-coding-standard-do-you-follow/17633875#17633875