# SQL Inner Join Few Process Few Dates

Tags: sql, inner-join

I want to near the today and different process and different dates. But my this code is getting last process all the date fields. But i want to, each customers the last process time to get.

```
        SELECT  (SELECT TOP 1 BORCLAR.BorcTarih FROM BORCLAR WHERE BORCLAR.BorcTarih <= getdate() order by BORCLAR.BorcTarih desc)as [TARİH], 
    MUSTERILER.Unvan,MUSTERILER.Ad + ' ' + MUSTERILER.Soyad AS [Adı Soyadı],
    MUSTERILER.Mahalle + ' ' + MUSTERILER.Cadde + ' '+MUSTERILER.Sokak + ' ' +
    MUSTERILER.ApartmanAdi+ ' NO:' +MUSTERILER.Numara + ' KAT:' + MUSTERILER.Kat + ' DAİRE:' 
    +MUSTERILER.Daire  AS [Adres],ARACSUBETANIMLAR.AracSubeAdi as [Araç/Şube Adı], ((SELECT SUM(BORCLAR.BorcTutari) FROM BORCLAR WHERE BORCLAR.BorcMusteriID=ODEMELER.OdemeMusteriID)-
    (SELECT SUM(ODEMELER.OdemeTutar) FROM ODEMELER where 
    BORCLAR.BorcMusteriID=ODEMELER.OdemeMusteriID)) AS [Borç Toplamı] FROM BORCLAR
        INNER JOIN ARACSUBETANIMLAR ON BORCLAR.BorcAracSube = ARACSUBETANIMLAR.AracSubeID
        INNER JOIN ODEMELER ON BORCLAR.BorcMusteriID = ODEMELER.OdemeMusteriID
        INNER JOIN MUSTERILER ON BORCLAR.BorcMusteriID = MUSTERILER.MusteriID where BORCLAR.BorcAracSube=1 and ((SELECT SUM(BORCLAR.BorcTutari) FROM BORCLAR WHERE BORCLAR.BorcMusteriID=ODEMELER.OdemeMusteriID)-(SELECT SUM(ODEMELER.OdemeTutar) FROM ODEMELER where BORCLAR.BorcMusteriID=ODEMELER.OdemeMusteriID)>0) group by MUSTERILER.Unvan,MUSTERILER.Soyad,
MUSTERILER.Ad,ARACSUBETANIMLAR.AracSubeAdi,
ODEMELER.OdemeMusteriID,BORCLAR.BorcMusteriID,
MUSTERILER.Cadde,MUSTERILER.Daire,MUSTERILER.ApartmanAdi,
MUSTERILER.Mahalle,MUSTERILER.Kat,MUSTERILER.Numara,
MUSTERILER.Sokak
```

Comment: . . Your question doesn't make sense.  Providing sample data and expected results is very helpful, especially with a language barrier.

Comment: Also, you really have to format the SQL to make it more readable. Take a look at this SO discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/522356/what-sql-coding-standard-do-you-follow