# Why are MySQL queries almost always written in Capital

Tags: mysql

I've seen most coders use Capital letters while writing MySQL queries, something like

```
 "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` = 1 ORDER BY `id` DESC"
```

I've tried writing the queries in small caps and it still works.

So is there any particular reason for not using small caps or is it just a matter of choice?

Comment: I'd say it's a matter of tradition mostly

Comment: +1 to tradition. Different languages have different code styles. Adhering to the style that is prevalent in a language helps readability.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's just a matter of readability. Keeping keywords in upper case and table/column names lower case means it's easier to separate the two when scan reading the statement .: better readability.

Most SQL implementations are case-insensitive, so you could write your statement in late 90s LeEt CoDeR StYLe, if you felt so inclined, and it would still work.

Comment: There's many times I've been reviewing others code and instances where they've specified keywords in lowercase has resulted in issues being missed due to skimming over large volumes of text.  Sticking to a standard of having all keywords in upper case prevents that as everyone involved is able to scan for them easily.

Comment: Case insensitivity is not limited to MySQL. Most of the SQL engine are case insensitive.

Comment: I think the SQL standard specifies case-insensitivity.

Comment: "Most SQL implementations"?  Are you sure that this shouldn't be "all"?  The answer would be better if you could be specific about this insensitivity being part of the standard or not; if it's not, then an example of a still standard-compliant SQL implementation which is not insensitive would be great; if it is, then this should be stated clearly.

Answer (score 1):

The case make no difference of the SQL engine. It is just a convention followed, just like coding conventions use in any of the programming languages

Answer (score 1):

You have to have a system - there are already a few questions on the site that deal with conventions and approaches.  Try:

[SQL formatting standards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519876/sql-formatting-standards)

Answer (score 0):

This is for readability sake.

Sometimes we have to write queries like that because our project (official) recommends.

But everything for readability and uniformity in a project.